# Calculating Heroku Slug Size Manually

Tags: heroku

I know a lot of people ask how to reduce the slug size. This isn't the case.

If slug size is the size of the gems + the code + other stuff, these all are kept in folders on the dyno, which means it can be access or at least measured.

What I'd like is to basically debug it to understand how the slug works by understanding what takes the most space

Is there a way to run a specific or several commands on heroku to get the size of the folders which are relevant for the slugs (i.e. gems folder is 20mb, code is 3mb, etc)?